# Does the listed price for domain transfer include registration for one year?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, domain-transfer

My website freelensia.com is currently hosted at GoDaddy. The renewal period has come and we are looking at different options since it seems GoDaddy increased its price by quite a bit. 32 USD for 2 years.
[image]

Whereas Namecheap charges 8.58 to transfer the domain
[image]

And Google Domains is around 12 USD to transfer the domain
[image]

My question is do these listed prices include one year registration or it is separate? And do I lose any remaining dates registered on the old registrar when I move to a new one? For example my domain expires on Feb 1 2021 but I transfer on Jan 1. If I register for one year, it will be until Jan 1 2022 not Feb 1 2022 right?

Answer (score 2):

Just to let everybody know, we did it for Name Cheap and

1. yes, we got the remaining dates carried over
2. yes, we got the one year extension on top of that

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do these listed prices include one year registration or it is separate?

You should ask the provider, it should be clearly explained.

You could suppose it includes one year extension BUT how transfers work depend on TLDs, hence registries, so you need to have the authoritative answer from your registrar.

At registry level, a `.com` like any other gTLD is extended by one year for a transfer (if not over the 10 years maximum limit required by ICANN). But a registrar is free to show its prices anyway it wants and can say: transfer is X on top of Y for the added year (and there is the ICANN fee that can be presented separately or not)

> And do I lose any remaining dates registered on the old registrar when I move to a new one?

In gTLDs, a transfer adds one year to the current expiration dates (except corner cases), so the end result is the same no matter when you do it during the lifetime of your domains.
With some constraints:

- you can not transfer during the 60 days after a creation (or potentially a former transfer)
- you shouldn't attempt transfer "around" the expiration date because it may work but you may have difficulties and even double payments (at old and new registrar); based on the rule above with the expiration date being extended, there is no reason to wait for the last moment to transfer it.